# How do I solve MySQL ERROR: Determine number of rows to copy: too many values to unpack Failed

Tags: mysql, database, database-migration

In trying to migrate a MSSQL database using the MySQLWorkbench Migration wizard, I get the error message **MySQL ERROR: Determine number of rows to copy: too many values to unpack Failed**  in the DATA MIGRATION stage precisely when its processing Bulk Data Transfer.

Comment: This seems to be a MySQL Migration Wizard bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77933